# C# - Memory management in a app that is periodicaly calling HttpWebRequest and WebBrowser

Tags: c#, memory-management, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control, httpwebresponse

### About:

I have this Windows Form application which every 60 seconds it captures information from two common web pages, do some simple string treatment with the result and do something (or not) based in the result.
One of those sites doesn't have any protection, so I can easily get it's HTML code using `HttpWebRequest` and it's `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`.
The other one has some code protection and I can't use the same approach. The solution was use the `WebBrowser` class to select all text of the site and copy to the clipboard, as *Jake Drew* posted [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/587458/GettingplusOnlyplusTheplusTextplusDisplayedplusOnp) (method 1).

### Extra information:

When the timer reachs 1 min, each method is asynchronously execuded using `Task`. At the end of each Task the main thread will search some information in those texts and take or not some decisions based in the result. After this process, not even the captured text will relevant anymore. Basically everything can be wipe out from memory, since I'll get everything new and process it in about 1 minute.

### Problem:

Everything is working fine but the problem is that it's gradually increasing the memory usage (about 20mb for each ticking), which are unecessary as I said before I don't need to maintain data in running in memory more than I had in the begin of app's execution:

[image]

and after comparing two snapshots I've found these 3 objects. Apparently they're responsible for that excess of memory usage:

[image]

So, even after I put the main execution in Tasks and do everything I could to help the Garbage Collector, I still have this issue.

**What else could I do to avoid this issue or dump the trash from memory??**

### Edit:

Here's the code that is capturing the HTML of the page using `HttpWebRequest`:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;
            if (response.CharacterSet == null) {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            } else {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }
            PB_value = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            readStream.Close(); //Ensure
        }
        response.Close(); //Ensure
    }
```

Comment: How did you help the Garbage Collector? Are the `WebResponse` object and related streams implicitly or explicitly disposed each time they're used? Are you using the `Microsoft Internet Controls` COM interfaces? How are those disposed/released? Can you post some code that shows how the cleaning task is accomplished? 200Mb can be something or it could be nothing. What's important is that the memory usage is not growing out of control. Does Windows reclaim  memory after your code has run for 12/24 hours, or it starts swapping and then everything drifts to oblivion?

Comment: @Jimi: Setting classes and variables that are no longer being used to null. Implicity, since I'm using `using` when it's getting the response. Nope. Im not using Ms Internet Controls, not that I know anyway. I did not tested it for more than 2 hours, until then, the usage keeps raising. As I said as per the application purpose, this amount of memory usage is unnatural because I dont need to keep any data or cache. I just perform these 4 steps each time: Donwload text information, analize it, decide, dump data. There's no reason to accumulate data in memory.  Im updating the post with more info

Comment: In the code you posted, the stream objects could be instantiated in a `Using` block. The encoding part could be discussed in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But this is not the part that's eating memory. The Code Project you linked uses the Activex COM interfaces (`SHDocVw`, `mshtml`). Internet Explorer, that is. I understand that's not actually under you direct control, so you have to rely on an external library *good behaviour*. Do you really need it? Isn't the .Net class (`WebBrowser`) enough for this task? Are those pages subject to scripting for completion?

Comment: @MWsan you should split this post into two: a question and an answer, and post the answer separately (via "Answer my own question" button). That would fit the SO format and would better help other people.

Comment: @Noseratio Noted. Thanks for the heads up bro. I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved:

After some research I've found a solution. I actually feel kind of ashamed because it is a quite simple solution that I haven't tried before, still, it's important to share.

The first thing I did was create an `Event` to identify when my two Tasks were finished then I assigned two functions to this event. The first function forced the Garbage Collector (`GC.Collect()`). The second function disposed the two Tasks, since all the main processes were done inside them (`T.Dispose()`). Then I've got the result I wanted:

[image]